# Azure SQL IAAS BCDR

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We are trying to set up Disaster Recovery for our IAAS SQL VMS. We currently have a network in our primary region and Althea exact same network in our secondary region so we can retain our IP addresses after failover.

The primary and secondary regions are not connected by a site to site or VNET peering link. We replicate our Domain controllers from on-premise but can’t work out how to replicate our databases from primary region in Azure.

What would be the best way to do that, replicate the VMs using disaster recovery tab in the VMs or replicate databases and build VMs around the databases in the event of a DR situation?

Thanks in advance and hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you using ASR azure to azure replication mechanism for flawless migration. This will allow you to create recovery points in the target region. When you configure replication, ASR generates application consistent recovery points which will ensure that SQL databases are also consistent. Relevant article :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-architecture.

Let me know if this helps.